# Распарсить строку на составляющие

Tags: c++, синтаксический-анализ

Есть строка вида:

> 482 у820рв Мария Львовна Закащикова* 9644 4855

Необходимо ее распарсить на составляющие:

- номер таксопарка (`int`),
- номер автомобиля (указатель на `wchar_t`, память выделена с лихвой),
- ФИО до звездочки (указатель на `wchar_t`, память выделена с лихвой),
- расход (`float`),
- прибыль(`float`).

Так как изначальная строка тоже двубайтовая - использую функцию swscanf.
Получается функция-парсер вида:

```
int ParserResult = swscanf(str, L" %i %6s %s[^*] %f %f", park_number, licence_plate_number, fsp, expense,profit);
```

Но, как можно понять, она не работает. Не считывается даже первый INT. Вопрос стандартный - где я идиот?

**UPD**
Во первых всем огромное спасибо за помощь и дельные советы. Исправляю свои ошибки и недомолвки, которые могли повлиять (и скорее всего повлияли) на видение проблемы и кода.
Суть программы - считать из файла структурированные данные в массив структур. Я решил делать это путем считывания сроки и парсинга ее на составляющие, следовательно я читаю данные не непосредственно в переменные, а в поля объектов массива.

```
struct TEntry { int park_number;
UnicodeString licence_plate_number;
UnicodeString fsp;  float expense;
float profit; };
```

Далее в функцию парсинга я передаю ТЕПЕРЬ УЖЕ (спасибо VladD) указатели на поля (Int и Float), а вместо полей типа UnicodeString я передаю результат функции c_str(), которая возвращает указатель на строку типа wchar_t.
Соответственно в конечном коде это выглядит вот так вот:

```
int ParserResult = swscanf(CurLine.c_str(), L" %i %s %[^*]* %f %f", &data [CurLineNumber].park_number),             data[CurLineNumber].licence_plate_number.c_str(),           data[CurLineNumber].fsp.c_str(),            &(data[CurLineNumber].expense),             &(data[CurLineNumber].profit));
```

**UPD2**
Исправив все нижеописанные ошибки, я получил необходимый эффект, ResultParser действительно стал в итоге равен 5, что значит, что все данные считались. Но столкнулся с другой проблемой - в полях написано все не русскими буквами, как надо, а, видимо, в иной кодировке. Соответственно возникает вопрос: как необходимо считывать данные из файлового потока wfstream в объект типа UnicodeString, минуя этот костыль и другие связанные, видимо с ним, ошибки?

```
wfstream input;   
UnicodeString CurLine;  
CurLine.SetLength(255);  
input.getline(CurLine.c_str(), 255);  
CurLine.SetLength(wcslen(CurLine.c_str()));
```

**UPD3**
Ссылка на код http://pastebin.com/DuMi0GfV

Comment: Хм. А зачем в начале форматной строки пробел? Это раз.
А во-вторых, для scanf-образных функций надо передавать адреса переменных, помните?

Comment: В начале форматной строки пробел, чтобы при чтении пропускались символы разделители, если в начале строки пробелы, поставленные пользователем, скажем, для отступа. А про адреса - это да, что касается инта и флоатов последних - исправил, теперь инт читается, а потом во все остальные переменные пишется мусор

Comment: @graalogosh, не расстраивайтесь. У меня тоже не работает. 

Проще считать, что все эти "хитрости" в `scanf()` отсутствуют и парсить подобные форматы входных данных вручную.

Comment: @VladD,  у меня там комментарии кончились. IMHO спор ни о чем.

1. Кода **автора вопроса** мы не видим.

2. В коде ответа массивы, а не указатели.

3. Да, если в scanf передать адрес указателя, то однозначно работать не будет.

И еще, трудно представить, что у **автора вопроса** `park_number`,`expense` и `profit` указатели на `int` и `float` и тут тоже будет ошибка.

Comment: @avp: Хм. Вы правы, подождём комментариев от автора.

Comment: Так а что у вас, windows или linux? И какая IDE или компилятор? Может просто файл сохранен не в utf-8 кодировке. А если Windows и Visual studio, то пишите setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian") и этого должно хватить.

Comment: Использую Embarcadero XE4 (в частности его часть, С++Builder) на Win7. Это требование ВУЗа, не мое. Файл сохранен с помощью Notepad++ в кодировке ANSI. В таком случае он читается, но в поля пишется косая кодировка. Если пересохранить файл в UTF-8, то парсер не присваивает вообще ни одного поля, чего в общем-то не должно было произойти. Если это может помочь, то так выглядит CurLine - строка для парсинга:
для файла в ANSI: "482 ó820ðâ Ìàðèÿ Ëüâîâíà Çàêàùèêîâà* 9644 4855";  
а так в UTF-8: "ï»¿482 Ñ820ÑÐ² ÐÐ°ÑÐ¸Ñ ÐÑÐ²Ð¾Ð²Ð½Ð° ÐÐ°ÐºÐ°ÑÐ¸ÐºÐ¾Ð²Ð°* 9644 4855"

Comment: Боже! Бедные мои глаза:

    input.getline(CurLine.c_str(), 255);

Делайте [так](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: А как вы файл пересохраняете? Вырезаете весь текст, потом выбираете utf-8, дальше вставляете текст и сохраняете файл?

Comment: У меня два файла: один в ANSI, другой в UTF-8 с одинаковым содержанием, ими и проверяю

Comment: Выложите все файлы, включая текстовые, на http://pastebin.com/ . Просто в одну вставку сделайте, разделяя названием файлов. Возможно потом кто-то уже точней укажет на проблему.

Comment: Разве там весь код?

Comment: Отсутствует функция из главного модуля, где я вызываю функцию LoadFromFile, ибо она не имеет непосредственного отношения к проблеме, зачем лишним кодом людей грузить? Приведу вызов функции здесь
TDataBase DataBase;    
TReadResult res = Form1->DataBase.LoadFromFile(Form1->OpenDialog1->FileName);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void){
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
  int park_number;
  wchar_t licence_plate_number[50];
  wchar_t fsp[50];
  float expense;
  float profit;
  wchar_t * str = L" 482 у820рв Мария Львовна Закащикова* 9644 4855";

  int ParserResult = swscanf(str, L" %i %6s %[^*]* %f %f", &park_number, &licence_plate_number, &fsp, &expense, &profit);

  wprintf(L" номер таксопарка : %d\n номер автомобиля %s\n ФИО : %s\n расход : %f\n прибыль : %f\n",
  park_number, licence_plate_number, fsp, expense, profit);
  return 0;
}
```

**UPD:** Разъяснения.
**Первая ошибка**
Если написать `%s[^*]`, то просто считывается первый набор символов до разделителя, то есть просто как если бы было указано `%s`, а `[^*]` выступает в роли разделителя, которого нету в строке, по этому вся остальная часть строки(Львовна Закащикова *9644 4855*) отбрасывается после безуспешных поисков последовательности символов `[ ^ * ]`.
 В итоге swscanf вернет тройку, потому как записал только значения `482` в `park_number` и `"у820рв"` в `licence_plate_number` и  `"Мария"` в `fsp`.

**Вторая ошибка**
 Если в формате не указать звездочку после просмотра набора символом, то есть не так `%[^*]*`, а так `%[^*]`, то swscanf не искал бы эту звездочка, и строка в `str` не соответствовала бы строке формата. Что в итоге бы привело к похожему результату из ошибки один, с единственной только разницей, что в переменную fsp записалось бы полное значение до звездочки, то есть не `"Мария"`, а `"Мария Львовна Закащикова"`, но остальная строка так же бы отбросилась, только уже не из за поиска символов `[^*]`, а из за поиска символа `*`.

Comment: @strol, так и в чем ошибка у @graalogosh?

Вы бы объяснили ему, что именно он должен подправить.

Кстати, без `#include <wchar.h>` не компилируется, а с названием локали "Russian"  в `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");` (по крайней мере у меня в xubuntu) просто не работает.

Comment: @avp: разница в том, что в ответе `licence_plate_number` объявлено как

    wchar_t licence_plate_number[50];

(то есть является _массивом_), следовательно, `&licence_plate_number` есть указатель _на этот массив_ (что численно совпадает с указателем на нулевой элемент).

В коде ТС же, должно быть, `licence_plate_number` объявлено как

    wchar_t *licence_plate_number;

а значит, `&licence_plate_number` есть адрес _указателя_ на массив, а не самого массива.

И в C есть свои тёмные углы.

Comment: @VladD, да нет же. На самом деле речь о том, что у ТС

    scanf("...%s[^*]..."

а нужно (как в ответе @strol)

    scanf("...%[^*]..."

т.е. **`%[`**, а не *`%s[`*. IMHO это основное.

--

А неразбериха c 

    scanf("...", &fsp, ...

или

    scanf("...", &fsp[0], ... // тут будет warning, но gcc сгенерит правильный код 

или

    scanf("...", fsp, ...

кажущаяся. Компилятор (в данном контексте) все это воспринимает.

Comment: @avp, по поводу setlocale и wchar_t, то у меня работало так, как в коде ответа написано, наверное потому что делал это в msvc++ 2010. Сейчас нет возможности проверить что там происходит в дистрибутивах линукса, но насколько я помню, то в ubuntu к примеру в gcc, я раньше не указывал кодировку, потому что и без неё работало.

Comment: Пробежался по онлайн компиляторам и там работает только если нету русских символов, то есть к примеру вот так http://ideone.com/juZsRY , а если есть русские символы, то вот так http://ideone.com/kuHujW . Такое впечатление, что функции в gcc или какие там компиляторы, не могут работать с русскими символами.

Comment: @strol, может Вы знаете, а может пока еще и нет, но строковые константы  в Си можно записывать и вот так


        wprintf(L" номер таксопарка : %d\n" 
                " номер автомобиля %s\n" 
                " ФИО : %s\n расход : %f\n прибыль : %f\n",

для большей наглядности. 

При компиляции (или препроцессором, точно не знаю) они "склеются".

Comment: @strol, на самом деле если русские буквы набивать в UTF-8, то можно указать локаль en_US.UTF-8 и они будут изображаться.

Но, даже если отбросить русские буквы и wchar, то основная-то ошибка у ТС просто в формате scanf. 

--

Вы когда ответы пишете, то не только код приводите, а и словами указывайте человеку, что нужно делать.

Comment: @avp: если бы проблемы, о которой я говорю, не было бы, то _вторая_ строка (`licence_plate_number`) прочиталась бы, и проблема была бы дальше.

Иллюстрация проблемы для читателей: <http://ideone.com/8uTUGc>, <http://ideone.com/C2jxyy>.

Comment: @VladD, Может Тс все-таки ошибся, потому как он написал, что 

> номер автомобиля (указатель на
> wchar_t, память выделена с лихвой)

То есть, или он он имел ввиду `wchar_t licence_plate_number[SIZE]`, или написал у себя `wchar_t * licence_plate_number = new wchar_t[SIZE];`. Если все-таки `new` или просто указатель на массив, то тогда да, вы правы. Кстати, не совсем очевидный момент. Можно легко на него попасть. Но скорей всего, что ТС имел ввиду wchar_t licence_plate_number[SIZE], потому как он не упоминал, что была какая-то ошибка, кроме той, что передавал не адреса в swscanf.